# Angularjs - Programmatically change radio button status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On a form-based application I'm developing, I get to use radio buttons for controlling boolean values. Everything goes well when changing their status via the user interface. However, I need to change the value of the radio at some point (changing the ng-model value). And here I face the problem that the radio button's [graphical] status does not change, but both radios de-select themselves. The value of the ng-model is set ok.

This is the HTML code I use:

```
<div class="radio-inline">
<label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"
    ng-value="true" ng-model="value.text" ng-checked="value.text">
    Active
</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"
        ng-value="false" ng-model="value.text"
        ng-checked="!value.text"> Inactive
    </label>
</div>
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Can you post some of your controller code? You say you change `value.text` programmatically so that would be the interesting part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ng-checked attribute on both attributes and properly initialize the value of value.text inside your controller :

```
var app = angular.module('app').
controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.value = {};
 $scope.value.text = false;
});
```

Comment: Awesome! It did work. The issue was that the value changing was done on a watcher, and it didn't give enough time to update the scope though. Adding a $timeout on such watcher, in conjunction with what you said fixed it all! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/catih/1/edit

js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

 $scope.value = {
   text : false
 };
  $scope.activate = function()
 {

   $scope.value.text = true;

 };

});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <button ng-click="activate()">Activate</button>

  <div class="radio-inline">
<label> 
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"
    ng-value="true" ng-model="value.text"  >
    Active
</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"
        ng-value="false" ng-model="value.text"
        > Inactive
    </label>
</div>
      </div>
</body>
```